# C# Core WebClient()

Tags: c#, httpclient, .net-core

В C# Core вместо WebClient() используется HttpClient(). Я не могу понять, как теперь сделать отправку данных. 
Ниже пример с использованием WebClient():

```
private void SendMessage(string message, int chatId)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var pars = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        pars.Add("text", message);
        pars.Add("chat_id", chatId.ToString());
        webClient.UploadValues(Link + "/sendMessage", pars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["text"] = message,
        ["chat_id"] = chatId.ToString()
    };
    string reply;
    using (var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict))
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Link + "/sendMessage", formContent))
        {
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                reply = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // иначе произошла ошибка, обрабатываем
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Вам придётся использовать async-метод, поскольку новое API асинхронно.